# WKWebView drawViewHierarchyInRect doesn't render webGL content on phone

Tags: ios, webgl, wkwebview

My app has a WKWebView that displays a web page containing some webGL content. I use drawViewHierarchyInRect to render the WKWebView to an image after the web page has loaded. This works fine on the simulator but on a phone the webGL content is not rendered to the image. The rest of the web page is rendered OK. On the phone the drawViewHierarchyInRect call returns false (the documentation says " returns false if the snapshot is missing image data for any view in the hierarchy").

Here is the code I am using:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webView.bounds.size, true, 0.0)

let drewOK = webView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(webView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

if (!drewOK)
{
    print("drawViewHierarchyInRect failed") // when the web page contains webGL this is printed on a phone but not in simulator
}

let overlayImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

photoPreview.image = overlayImage
```

This problem happens on both iOS 9 and iOS 10.

Is there something else I need to do to make it work on a phone?

A demo project is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/jedsoane/TestWKWebViewImageCapture).

Comment: haven't found solution either. `takeSnapshotWithConfiguration:completionHandler:` also doesn't capture webgl content.

Answer (score 0):

yes, i also meet this problem. i have try many methods, but cant solve it.
only way may be look like this: set WebGLRenderer's 'preserveDrawingBuffer' is true, call canvas' 'toDataURL' to make a snapshot, then send it to app, save it at the end.